# SQL - Creating View using Values from Present and Previous Years

Tags: sql, sql-view, mysql-5.7

Below is a simplified version of a View I want to create:

```
+----+-------------+---------+-------------+---------+
| ID | FISCAL_YEAR | REVENUE | YOY_NUMERIC | YOY_PCT |
+----+-------------+---------+-------------+---------+
|  1 |        2014 |    1000 |             |         |
|  2 |        2015 |     800 |        -200 |   -20.0 |
|  3 |        2016 |    1200 |         400 |    50.0 |
|  4 |        2017 |    1350 |         150 |    12.5 |
|  5 |        2018 |    1100 |        -250 |   -18.5 |
+----+-------------+---------+-------------+---------+
```

Let's say the values in columns `FISCAL_YEAR` and `REVENUE` come from a table called `REVENUE_DATA`. Simple math needs to be done to populate the `YOY_` columns. I'm not sure how to go about making this work assuming the following caveats are present in the underlying table `REVENUE_DATA`:

- Some fiscal year may not have a revenue data
- Some fiscal year could be missing entirely

If either one of the above edge cases is true, then the affected year should still have a row in the View; it just wouldn't have the values for `REVENUE` and the `YOY_` columns.

Comment: If appropriate, consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on

Comment: What's the version of MySQL? 5.x or 8.x?

Comment: "Some fiscal year could be missing entirely" -- Then... what's the range of years you want to show?

Comment: @TheImpaler - The range is essentially all of the fiscal years found in the source table.

Comment: We need the version of the MySQL "database engine", where the `SELECT` runs.

Comment: I did `SELECT version()` and got 5.7.23

Comment: This can be done using CTEs and the LAG() function, assuming that you have MySQL 8.x. If you have MySQL 5.x, then you're out of luck; you will need to process it in the application side.

Comment: Yep, that's the version.

Comment: Without a table that has all the years you want, this is somewhere between really hard and not possible in a MySQL view.